# Gitlab-CI, run on schedule but only if there are changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to deploy my project once per day, but only if there have been changes.
There is a specific hour each that I am able to deploy during and I am comfortable with using a scheduled pipeline to trigger and deploy.

However, there aren't always changes that require deployment. Ideally, if there have been no changes to the code base since the last deployment, the pipeline wouldn't run that day.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You'll need some external state, storing the last commit you built. Then each day you can check if the latest commit is the last commit you built, and skip the build if it is.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a 4 years old feature request [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 19813](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/19813)

> ### GitLab CI only execute when a certain folder has changed
>
> I have quite a large project, and I'm using GitLab CI with Pages to deploy it, however, when I change anything in the repo, it runs CI.
>
> I don't want this to happen, I want it to run only if the `src` folder changes.
> Is this possible?

The recent (July 2020) conclusion is to use [`only:changes`/`except:changes`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges)

> Using the `changes` keyword with `only` or `except` makes it possible to define if a job should be created based on files modified by a Git push event.

Example:

> I wanted this feature especially for `package.json` and `package-lock.json` because I can run `npm install` only if there is changes.

```
  only:
    changes:
      - package.json
      - package-lock.json
```

Warning, as noted by [Matthijs Bierman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226449/matthijs-bierman) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525941/gitlab-ci-run-on-schedule-but-only-if-there-are-changes/63565982?noredirect=1#comment113608523_63565982), and as [documented here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#using-onlychanges-with-scheduled-pipelines):

> Note that `only: changes` does *not* work with `when: scheduled`

Comment: Note that `only: changes` does not work with `when: scheduled`.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#using-onlychanges-with-scheduled-pipelines

Comment: @MatthijsBierman Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants. This only depends on the last push event. If many days pass without any push event, the job should only run once, not each day.

Comment: @Julien Would it be acceptable to define another job, running daily, whose sole action would be to call this one as downstream? (and the downstream job, as described in the answer, would only run if changes are detected)

Comment: Yes, that'd be great, but what would be an easy way to detect such change?

Comment: @Julien The rule I mention in the answer (which will be called once a day, as explained in the previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate Branch **dev** on Git where you store your an hourly changes of code and at the end of the day You can merge it with **Master** branch which trigger build on Git CI.

Generally Master is default branch for deployment of Git CI. you can change it to different branch as well.