# Schedule Gitlab-ci job only if commits

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, schedule

We have a project with a pipeline that is resource intensive, so there could be a case where if many commits were to happen relatively close to each other, pipelines may fail. I was looking into having triggering the pipeline only through a schedule, like every 3 hours. However I wouldnt want it to trigger if no commits were made or during the night time. It is possible to schedule but only if commits were made since the last scheduled pipeline?

pseudo gitlab-ci.yml:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
    - when: never

stage:
 - job1
 - job2
 - job3
```

Comment: This question has already been asked: [Gitlab-CI, run on schedule but only if there are changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525941/gitlab-ci-run-on-schedule-but-only-if-there-are-changes). Currently there is no built-in GitLab feature to do what you want. There is an open [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18868), but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: I see...thanks. For now I've implemented a workaround..for every scheduled pipeline it will save the its current commit hash to global variable. so then the next schedule will check if its current commit hash is the same as the one saved previously. if its not then schedule, if it is the same don't do anything.

Comment: @JasonChen How do you do that without the variable being lost between runs?

Comment: I got myself into the same situation and solved it by storing sha of a commit to a dotenv artifact which on the next schedule run is retrieved and compared to current one. Unfortunately, there should be job that would fetch it first, store again as dotenv which would be passed to next job that can decide if we should for example trigger next pipeline or not. Kind of tricky but works for me. The other option is to push tag on schedule, and on the next schedule run check if current commit contains tag, if yes that means there are no changes. In my case looked too messy in git tree